# Update Artifactory properties - No properties could be found

Tags: rest, artifactory

I am able to retrieve the property set in one of the directory in Artifactory with REST

```
curl -u <username> -xget "<path_to_a_folder>/?properties=retention.days"
```

Output

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "retention.days" : [ "730" ]
  },
  "uri" : "<path_to_a_folder>"
}
```

But when I try to update `retention.days`, it return not found error
Is my REST request incorrect?

```
curl -u <username> -xpatch "<path_to_a_folder>/?properties=retention.days=365&recursive=0"
```

Output

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "No properties could be found."
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using Patch which does not seem be expected. It should be PUT. I have a set a value 300 for the parameter retention.days. GET shows the below result.

```
curl -uadmin:"Password" -X GET "http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/storage/example-repo-local/folder1/folder2/?properties=retention.days"
{
  "properties" : {
    "retention.days" : [ "300" ]
  },
  "uri" : "http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/storage/example-repo-local/folder1/folder2"
}%
```

Now I used the bleow command to reset this value.

```
curl -uadmin:"Password1" -X PUT "http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/storage/example-repo-local/folder1/folder2/?properties=retention.days=200&recursive=1"
```

This recursively set the value to 200. If I try to set it now.

```
"properties" : {
    "retention.days" : [ "200" ]
  }
```

Give a try with this command.

Comment: I also tried `put` earlier the day., and it failed. After numerous attempts, I found out that it must be capital `-XPUT` instead of `-xput` !